# Admob Banner Ad not loading in Android

Tags: android, firebase, admob

My Admob Banner ad in not loading.

Toast displays that "Banner add is loaded".

I tried many other solutions provided on stackoverflow but none seemed to work for me.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mBannerAd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBannerAd = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.banner_ad);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("A5E3E2068BD88202CBC281AD7XXXXXXX")
                .build();
        mBannerAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        mBannerAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Closing the Banner Ad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Banner Ad is loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.akapoor.shayri.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/banner_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3180111609438244/24179XXXXX" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.akapoor.shayri">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ShayariText"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: take a look at your logs to get error code from admob. Update error to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:-

- You have complete the steps mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start) to display a test ad
  successfully
- This is not a test ad but an actual ad unit.
- You have replaced test ad unit ID with the actual ad unit ID

If these steps are done, then It will take an hour or two to get your ad unit displayed in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. You should remove the test devices, `addTestDevice`, though:

Change:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("A5E3E2068BD88202CBC281AD7XXXXXXX")
    .build();
```

to:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `MobileAds` in `onCreate()` like this:

`MobileAds.initialize(MainActivity.this,"YOUR_APP_ID));`